# How do I make the main form show only if the user login is successful from a second form?

Tags: c#, verification, inputverifier

I am trying to make a form that verifies user login. I want that form to show first then, if the user login is successful, the main form should show.

this is what I have tried(in the second form):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string funame = "thename";
        string dep = "thedep";
        string unm = "theusername";
        string ups = "thepassword";

        User cs = new User(funame, dep, unm, ups);

        if (cs.validateLogin(unm, ups));
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + funame + " of " + dep);

            frmPurchaseDiscountedItem fpd = new frmPurchaseDiscountedItem();
            fpd.Show();
        }

        

    }
```

The problem is the main form always pops out first.

It should be something like:

*2nd form pops up then, if user is verified, main form pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround.

You don't need to change "start form" in `Program.cs`. You can open the main window at the beginning and hide it. Then create a Login instance and show it.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Login login = new Login(this);
        // hide MainForm
        this.Hide();
        // show Login
        login.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

If login button in `Login form` clicked, show the `MainForm` and close `Login form`.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private MainForm mainform = null;

    public Login(MainForm main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // get MainForm instance
        this.mainform = main;
    }

    // if success
    bool success = true;

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(success) // check login here
        {
            // show main form
            mainform.Visible = true;
            // close login form
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, if you click the `X button` in the upper right corner of the `Login form`, it will also show the hidden `MainForm` (if user doesn't want to login, close the application). We can avoid it by overriding `WndProc`.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && ((int)msg.WParam == SC_CLOSE))
    {
        // click the 'X' button to close the application
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
```